# Inserting several prefixed namespaces in an xml message

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to carry out an xslt transformation but I don't get the results I would like. I need to insert several namespaces with their prefixes into an xml message.

This is the message I get:

```
  <Operation>        
     <SessionId>?</SessionId>        
     <appUser>            
        <number1>?</number1>            
        <field2>?</field2>            
        <Properties>
           <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
           <KeyValue>
              <Key>?</Key>
              <Value>?</Value>
           </KeyValue>
        </Properties>            
        <value3>?</value3>            
     </appUser>
  </Operation>
```

This is the transformation I do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="ser:{name()}" namespace="http://www.url.com/Services">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[ancestor::appUser]">
  <xsl:element name="mp:{name()}" namespace="http://schemas.data.org/myPath">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::KeyValue ]">
    <xsl:element name="arr:{name()}" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And i get the following:

```
<ser:Operation xmlns:ser="http://www.url.com/Services">        
         <ser:SessionId>?</ser:SessionId>        
         <ser:appUser>            
            <mp:number1 xmlns:mp="http://schemas.data.org/myPath">?</mp:number1>            
            <mp:field2 xmlns:mp="http://schemas.data.org/myPath">?</mp:field2>            
            <mp:Properties xmlns:mp="http://schemas.data.org/myPath">
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <arr:KeyValue xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                  <arr:Key>?</arr:Key>
                  <arr:Value>?</arr:Value>
               </arr:KeyValue>
            </mp:Properties>            
            <mp:value3 xmlns:mp="http://schemas.data.org/myPath">?</mp:value3>            
         </ser:appUser>
      </ser:Operation>
```

But I don't like seeing the namespace declaration xmlns:mp="http://schemas.data.org/myPath" in every element.

So, could I modify my xslt to get something like the following?

```
<ser:Operation xmlns:ser="http://www.url.com/Services" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.data.org/myPath">        
         <ser:SessionId>?</ser:SessionId>        
         <ser:appUser>            
            <mp:number1 >?</mp:number1>            
            <mp:field2>?</mp:field2>            
            <mp:Properties>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <arr:KeyValue xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                  <arr:Key>?</arr:Key>
                  <arr:Value>?</arr:Value>
               </arr:KeyValue>
            </mp:Properties>            
            <mp:value3>?</mp:value3>            
         </ser:appUser>
      </ser:Operation>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: A change like this is purely cosmetic - it has nothing to do with the semantics of XML documents.

Since you are using XSLT 2.0, use the `xsl:namespace` instruction on the outermost element of the XML document and declare the `mp:` namespace there. The way to do this is writing a separate template for `Operation`:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
```

Construct a new element that is prefixed with `ser:`

```
<xsl:element name="ser:{name()}">
```

and add another namespace node to this element:

```
<xsl:namespace name="mp" select="'http://schemas.data.org/myPath'"/>
```

Then, the XSLT processor will refrain from serializing redundant namespace declarations in the output.

Also, your stylesheet is more readable if you declare all namespaces in the `xsl:stylesheet` element, not somewhere else in the code.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ser="http://www.url.com/Services"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.data.org/myPath"
  xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">

 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:element name="ser:{name()}">
     <xsl:namespace name="mp" select="'http://schemas.data.org/myPath'"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="ser:{name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="appUser/*">
  <xsl:element name="mp:{name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::KeyValue ]">
    <xsl:element name="arr:{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<ser:Operation xmlns:mp="http://schemas.data.org/myPath"
               xmlns:ser="http://www.url.com/Services">
   <ser:SessionId>?</ser:SessionId>
   <ser:appUser>
      <mp:number1>?</mp:number1>
      <mp:field2>?</mp:field2>
      <mp:Properties><!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <arr:KeyValue xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <arr:Key>?</arr:Key>
            <arr:Value>?</arr:Value>
         </arr:KeyValue>
      </mp:Properties>
      <mp:value3>?</mp:value3>
   </ser:appUser>
</ser:Operation>
```

Of course you could declare all namespaces on the outermost element (`arr:` too), which would - again - be a cosmetic measure.

Comment: Thank you very much. It has been really helpful and instructive.